# Beancomparator not working with null values

Tags: java

My requirements is to sort list of Customer type beans according to `customername` property in that bean... for that i used `beancomparator`.it is working fine when `customername` field is not `null`.
It is throwing `NullPointerException` when the field is `null`..please help me out..

my code is

```
public class customer{
private String customername;
}

main()
{
list<customer> list=new arraylist();
//list is filled with customertype beans
comparator<customer> comp=new beancomparator(customername);
collections.sort(list,comp);//throwing error when customername is null...
}
```

Comment: when its `null` it will throw `NullPointerException` so better handle that `null` case like as suggested by @jigar

Comment: Is it the need of your program to put `null` as Customer name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the case of nullity check in your `Comparator`

```
new Comparator<Customer>() {

public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
    if(o1.getName() == null){ return -1;}

    if(o2.getName() == null){ return 1;}
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: thanks @Jigar and can u please tell me in which order it is sorting I mean am getting list in descending order.does it returns default descending order

Comment: You can just try it :) it should be like ab first then bc then cd all thee null ones in the end

Answer (score 14):

I use it this way:

```
    Comparator<Customer> comparator = new BeanComparator(customername, new NullComparator(false));
    if (descentSort){
        comparator = new ReverseComparator(comparator);
    }
    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

IMO it is easier way :)